@ColumnTransformer on a @ManyToMany relationship
I have a Java class with these fields:
@Entity
public class Car {

  @Column(name = "NAME", columnDefinition = "bytea")
  @ColumnTransformer(read = “pgp_sym_decrypt(name, ‘mySecretKey’)”, write = “pgp_sym_encrypt(?, ‘mySecretKey’)”)
  private String name;

  @ManyToMany
  @JoinTable(name = "STUDENT_CAR", 
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "CAR", referencedColumnName = "NAME", columnDefinition = "bytea"), 
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "STUDENT",referencedColumnName="NAME", columnDefinition="bytea"))
  private List<Student> students;

}

I'd like to use the columnTransformer annotation even on the field students with the ManyToMany annotation.
I tried to apply the columnTransformer on that but It doesn't encrypt/decrypt the columns of the "STUDENT_CAR" table.
Does anyone know another way to make it work?
Thank you all.

@ColumnTransformer works on, as the name implies, columns not on complex mappings. Not sure what you think it should encode? If you want that create an additional entity StudentCar to do the mapping instead of an @JoinTable annotation and put the @ColumnTransformer on the columns for that entity.
